# Is there a way to reconstruct a query from info of a graphql.js resolver?

Tags: graphql

```js
    let root = {
        books: (parent, args, info) { ... }
    }
    let res = await graphql(schema, `{ books { title } }`, root);
```

Is there already a helper function in graphql.js to reconstruct the query using the `info`?

Answer (score 0):

yes there is a way:

When you use graphqlHTTP from express-graphql, the 3rd argument is graphQLParams, you can give it the context for instance.

```
graphqlHTTP(async (request, response, graphQLParams) => ({
    schema,
    graphiql: true,
    context: graphQLParams
}))
```

Then in your schema definition, you can grab the context from any resolve function like this:

```
products: {
        type: new GraphQLList(productType),
        resolve: (parent, args, { query }, info) => {
            return getProducts({
                query
            });
        }
    },
```

context.query is your actual query in this example its:

```
{ products { id } }
```